# app rotation does not work in ipod

Tags: ios, ipod-touch

I have created my universal app for iOs devices.
I have enabled rotation of devices.
But when i rotate my iPod in landscape mode, my app does not get rotated. 
In simulator rotation works perfectly.
Other apps like safari browser, mail app are rotated.
Is there any problem with my app or it happen in iPod touch?

Comment: @ExcelledProducts he enabled rotation on devices

Comment: there may be an issue with iOS version you are targeting since orientation support for the app has changed quite a bit since iOS 5.You can read [this] (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges/RespondingtoDeviceOrientationChanges.html), it will surely help you.

Comment: my ipod touch has ios version 5.1

Comment: @ExcelledProducts No, in `plist` file.

Comment: @Alex WOULD YOU PLEASE SHOW US YOUR CODE IN YOUR APP

Comment: Well code wise , you could get direct orientation sensor calls, and then manually rotate your views programmatically.

Comment: or update ur iOS version on iPod .